# Display time signature as single number above the staff

Tags: notation, time-signatures, lilypond

Sometimes, when a piece of music has a frequently-changing time signature, the time signature is printed above the staff. In the following example, only the numerator is printed (the denominator is 4 throughout):

[image: Example]

I know that this could be achieved in LilyPond by hiding the usual time signatures and manually displaying the numbers. Is it possible to do this by modifying the time signature engraver instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a variation of [this snippet](http://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=272) and use a dynamics context to display the time signatures, like in the following example:

```
\version "2.18.2"

\score {
  <<
  \new Dynamics {
    \time 2/4 s2
    \time 3/4 s2.
    \time 4/4 s1
  }
  \new Staff \relative c' {
    \key es \major
    \clef treble
    << { g'8[-3^\markup { \italic "sempre legato" } a b] s } \\ 
       { es,[-3\pp f g <b, d>] } >>
    << { es[-2 f-1 g a <g-1 b-4> <as-2 c-5>] } \\
       { c,[-4 d es f] s s } >>
    << { s es[-2 f g-1 a b c d]-5 } \\
       { <b,-5 d>[ c d es f g-3 a b] } >>
  } 
  >>

  \layout {
    \context {
      \Score
      \override SpacingSpanner.base-shortest-duration = #(ly:make-moment 1/32) 
    }
    \context {
      \Dynamics
      \consists "Time_signature_engraver"
      \override TimeSignature.style = #'single-digit
      \override TimeSignature.break-align-symbol = ##f
      \override TimeSignature.X-offset = #ly:self-alignment-interface::x-aligned-on-self
      \override TimeSignature.self-alignment-X = #CENTER
      \override TimeSignature.after-line-breaking = #shift-right-at-line-begin
    }
    \context {
       \Staff
       \remove "Time_signature_engraver"
    }
  }
}
```

The above should render as:

[image]

---

If you only want to change one single Dynamics context, you can also use

[...]

```
  \new Dynamics \with {
    \consists "Time_signature_engraver"
    \override TimeSignature.style = #'single-digit
    \override TimeSignature.break-align-symbol = ##f
    \override TimeSignature.X-offset = #ly:self-alignment-interface::x-aligned-on-self
    \override TimeSignature.self-alignment-X = #CENTER
    \override TimeSignature.after-line-breaking = #shift-right-at-line-begin
  } {
    \time 2/4 s2
    \time 3/4 s2.
    \time 4/4 s1
  }
```

[...]

And delete the stuff from `\layout`.

Comment: This is great, but settings in \layout { \context { \Dynamics } } affect every Dynamics context in this score-block. What should be done to get this effect if there is another unrelated Dynamics context, e.g. one containing dynamics or one containing piano-pedalling?

Comment: You are right. You can directly put the directions into the relevant Dynamics context with `\with`. See my edit.